# Reading environmental variables set in configmap of kubernetes pod from react application?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

I have a react application which reads a couple of API related environmental variables.

1. When running off a local machine or a VM, the API variables are read correctly into the application.
2. When hardcoded into the react application itself, the application runs too.

However, creating a pod in Kubernetes with the **image** and a **configmap** does not work - the application runs but the environmental variables are not set.

**pod.yaml**

```
...
 spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: configmap
        image: xxxxx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
...
```

**configmap**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  API_HOST: xxxxxxx
  SOME_ID: abcdef
  NODE_ENV: development
  PROVIDER: GCP
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: xxxx
  name: configmap
  namespace: xxxx
  resourceVersion: xxxx
  selfLink: xxxx
  uid: xxxx
```

**React snippet**

```
    if(!process.env.SOME_ID) {
      console.log('ID')
    }
```

My trouble lies with passing the environmental variables to the React application. I am certain the environmental variables are setup correctly in the pods but seemingly, the client-side React application does not have these variables (i.e. `console.log` prints nothing).

I chanced upon this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/) doing something similar but with Docker. It mentions that the transpiling replaces all `process.env` with a string value. The trick given to mitigate this bash script which creates JavaScript file with environment variables assigned as properties of the global window object.

While I am unsure if this is doable in Kubernetes, I am wonder is there an easier way to inject environmental variables of a Kubernetes pod into a react application at runtime?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question. React is mostly a browser-side SPA framework, not something that runs on a server. Env vars are only visible to whatever is actually running on your server-side. I would guess this is some kind of NodeJS application, but you would have to add code in that app to read from env vars and expose them to the browser somehow.

Comment: did you check `env:` syntax? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work as you expect because the `process.env` variables are replaced during transpiling. You can't access them during runtime.

You can check this guide for one possible solution: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/. But regarding your question, there is nothing wrong with your Kubernetes configuration.